# Can this prior be considered "Uninformative"

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, prior, posterior

I am talking about the typical Normal, $p(Z) \sim N(0, I)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Thing is, that it assumes independence, but it isnt uniform.

Comment: What's your definition of uninformative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. You assumed *a priori* (1) zero means, (2) unit marginal variances and (3) zero correlation between variables -- this has nothing to do with making "no assumptions".